# document.readystate throwing COMException

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, exception, automation, mshtml

I am working on a mshtml C# IE 11 automation based project, when I log in to the website and check the readystate property of the document, it throws a COMException. The same code works for IE 8 without any issue:

```
while (document.readyState != "complete")
{
//do nothing
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you provide us with the `ToString` of the `COMException`?

Comment: **'doc.readyState'** threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'. Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Comment: @HansPassant - For html document of SHDocVw.InternetExplorer there is no DocumentCompleted event. Can you help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `document.readyState` instead of `doc.readyState`